# How to insert a method into SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, methods, sqldatareader

I am trying to pass a method into a `SqlDataReader`, so I have this method1 which gets the list of data and I have method2 which gets numbers of goods purchased by a specific `CustomerID` when I run the program I get error saying `"Index was outside the bounds of the array."`

```
 public List<Staff> method1()
{
    List<Staff> LBD = new List<Staff>();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection etc...
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL query goes here)

    conn.Open();
    SqlDatadata data = command.Executedata();
    while (data.Read())
    {
        Staff l = new Staff();
        l.IsStaff = data["IsStaff"].ToString();
        l.Name = data["Name"].ToString();
        l.Name = Convert.ToInt32(reader[this.method2(reader["ID"].ToString())]);

        ........
        LBD.Add(l);
    }
    conn.Close();
    return LBD;
}

        public int method2(string ID)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new ......
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select COUNT (RowName) from TableName WHERE ID=@ID", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RowName", ID);

        conn.Open();
        int x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return x;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Id will be higher or lower or this id not available in reader array

so check it properly...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using same column as in `database`. I think you are using something wrong column name.